# MassTransit 5.2, SignalR: How can i get the IHubContext inside my Consumer?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, masstransit

My main problem is to get the right instance of the SignalR hub.

Context: Im building a webapplication which communicates with a couple of external systems. CRUD operations in my application result in updating the databases of the external systems.

In this example i have 3 services running:

ExternalSystem | StateMachine | .NET CORE WebAPI

When i post the 'create employee' form, a RabbitMQ message will be sent from the WebAPI to the statemachine. The statemachine then sends a couple of create messages to my external system service which updates the database. Thereafter, it updates the statemachine to keep track of the createoperation.

Form -> API -> StateMachine -> ExternalSystem -> StateMachine -> API

So far so good. Now i would like to use SignalR to send the status updates to the client. So i've implemented this consumer in the API:

```
public class UpdatesConsumer :
    IConsumer<IExternalSystemUpdateMessage>
{
    private readonly IHubContext<UpdatesHub> _updaterHubContext;

    public UpdatesConsumer(IHubContext<UpdatesHub> hubContext)
    {
        _updaterHubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IExternalSystemUpdateMessage> context)
    {
        //return _updaterHubContext.Clients.Group(context.Message.CorrelationId.ToString()).SendAsync("SEND_UPDATE", context.Message.Message);// this.SendUpdate(context.Message.CorrelationId, context.Message.Message);
        return _updaterHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SEND_UPDATE", context.Message.Message);
    }
}
```

This is my SignalR hub:

```
public class UpdatesHub :
    Hub
{
    public Task SendUpdate(Guid correlationId, string message)
    {
        return Clients.Group(correlationId.ToString()).SendAsync("SEND_UPDATE", message);
    }
}
```

And this is how the Bus and consumer is instantiated:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _services = services;

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR();            
        //services.AddSingleton<IHubContext<UpdatesHub>>();

        WebAPI.CreateBus();
    }

    public static IServiceCollection _services;

    static IBusControl _busControl;
    public static IBusControl Bus
    {
        get
        {
            return _busControl;
        }
    }

    public static void CreateBus()
    {
        IRMQConnection rmqSettings = Config.GetRMQConnectionConfig("rmq-settings.json", "connection");

        _busControl = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            var host = x.Host(BusInitializer.GetUri("", rmqSettings), h =>
            {
                h.Username(rmqSettings.UserName);
                h.Password(rmqSettings.Password);
            });

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "externalsystems.update",
                e => { e.Consumer(() => new UpdatesConsumer((IHubContext<UpdatesHub>)Startup.__serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IHubContext<UpdatesHub>)))); });
        });

        TaskUtil.Await(() => _busControl.StartAsync());
    }
```

=========================================================================

So the problem is that _updaterHubContext.Clients in my Consumer class, always turn out to be empty. I've tested accessing the hub in a controller, and the clients do show up:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<UpdatesHub> _hubContext;
    public TestController(IHubContext<UpdatesHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Test/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

How can i get the right instance of the hub in my Consumer class? Or how can i access the IServiceCollection that .net is using?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your consumer so that MassTransit will resolve it from the `IServiceProvider` using the support provided in the MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection package.

```
x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "externalsystems.update", e => 
{
    e.Consumer<UpdatesConsumer>(_serviceProvider);
});
```

Be sure to register your `UpdatesConsumer` in the container as well. This should resolve a new instance of the consumer for each message received on the endpoint.

Comment: Thnx! This was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not register Bus using [Microsoft Dependency Injection](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/msdi.html). It should fix your issue, it will Resolve your consumer using `IServiceProvider`

Comment: Thnx for the sample page. It contributed to te elegance of my solution. Especially the sample project in the link